# Div side by side like table cell

Tags: html, css

I want to have two divs side by side and define width for only one div.

Then, the other div would auto-fit the parent container. How do I do that?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}
.parent .first {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.parent .last {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add `display :inline` to the child divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't `float` the second div.  Only the first one needs to be floated.

http://jsfiddle.net/zLef8/

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano because when you float an element it will only be as wide as its contents unless you specify a width even if it is `display: block`.  `display: block` elements fill up all available width in the line

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first">test</div>
    <div class="last">test2</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}
.parent > .first {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.parent > .last {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align:left
}
```

example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMCbx/1/)